# How could a fascist/far-right party have risen to power in 1930s USA?

Tags: society, warfare, alternate-history, government, politics

In the real world, while the Great Depression hit the United States quite badly, several factors meant that fascist parties and organisations never really gained the traction they did in the US, as compared to other nations like Germany. My question thus has the following 2 parts:

1. What local fascist/far-right party has the highest chance of coming into power? (Hence this discounts the installation of fascist governments by foreign powers).
2. What are the events and occurrences within our timeline that have to change in order to allow this party to come into power?

Comment: There were any? I mean USA were fighting inner (and outer) communism and thus all marginal political movements that looked like something communistic. So I doubt there were any real "non-standart" parties (like Libertarians now)

Comment: In the 30s, there were many popular far-right movements and organisations in America. The KKK, Silver Legion of America, Fascist League of North America, etc.; radical movements were actually much more common during that time than it is now, due to many reasons (for e.g. fascism was still seen as a viable alternative by many, as the War had not begun yet, and Nazism and fascism as a whole still had not been exposed for its true evil).

Comment: On top of that, proto-fascist politicians were in power during the time. Like Huey Long, Governor of Louisiana. It's just that I'm not sure how these organisations and politicians could have come to power.

Comment: My personal opinion is that absence of USSR but also fall of Russian Empire (i.e. win of White Army) would greatly benefit to all right movements in all over the world. But I can't post it like answer because it just opinion. I have little facts on this.

Comment: I'd advise to get rid of the third question. "How will this affect history"-type questions are broad enough on their own, and coupling it with letting the answerer make up their own kind of scenario for a Fascist USA means there are infinitely many possible answers.

Comment: In re your comment ... Huey Long was in Louisiana; you seem to misunderstand where the center of gravity of American Political power was in the 1930's; you'll want to head north of the Mason Dixon line to do so.  On the terms of reference that you are using, Long was irrelevant.

Comment: If the Confederacy won the Civil War, then political power would be centered south of the Dixon line instead of North; so, ppl like Huey P Long would have had a lot more influence.

Comment: It's not a whole answer, but if the USSR had intervened in China early, driving back Japan, then invaded Europe as Hitler was rebuilding the German army, Nazis and fascists could have come out looking like heroes from WW2, with liberal US isolationist governments looking like ineffectual weaklings. Slightly later than what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 4):

### What fascist/far-right party has the highest chance of coming into power?

The Nazi party.

They had significant amounts of support in the United Kingdom, the U.S., and, of course, Germany.

### What are the events and occurrences within our timeline that have to change in order to allow this party to come into power?

A delay in the [abdication of Edward VIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_VIII_abdication_crisis).

On December 10, 1936 British King Edward VIII signed a document giving up the throne after only 11 months on it. The government was in revolt against Edward's decision to marry [Bessie Wallis Warfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_Simpson), also known as Wallis Simpson. At the kings coronation, Wallis Simpson appeared at the king's side. At the time (and until October of that year) she remained married to British tycoon [Ernest Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Simpson). Wallis Simpson was accused by the government of being a Nazi agent. This charge wasn't proven, but the King and his wife's loyalties were with the German Nazi party. After the abdication in 1937, the couple visited Hitler at his private residence in Obersalzberg, and reportedly greeted the German Chancellor publicly with Nazi salutes.

The British Monarch does not make decisions and can not dictate policy. So, it is possible that if Edward VIII had not abdicated, a Churchill Prime Minister would still have declared war on Germany. History for Europe may remain unchanged.

### From Edward VIII to a U.S. Nazi Party

When Edward came to the throne it started off a great re-ordering of power brokers. Who had access to the King and who didn't.

Although the aristocracy and magnates might differ with the King politically in private, for the sake of their reputations and continued access that a relationship with the monarch provides, many would publicly align with the King's support of Germany.

Beyond just international business interests, many U.S. Tycoons had family connections to Great Britain. Many American families had married off children in a process that was criticized as "buying titles". Although, in many instances, the American head of the family differed with their British in-laws, the re-ordering allegiances of the aristocracy to remain in alignment with the King on sympathies with the Nazi party would have caused shift in allegiances among the U.S. wealthy as well.

This would have taken the form of public statements and financial support to the U.S. Nazi party, which already had operations in the United States.

Like the King, the American tycoons also had their own halo of smaller business owners who might not have sympathized privately with the German National Socialists, but saw nothing to gain in not publicly appearing to be in alignment with their biggest customers, or those they aspired to do business with. As a result, the halo effect extended from the British monarch through American businessmen would be significant in therms of public positive statements, financial support, and volunteers. It's possible the party would be able to start putting up candidates for state and national audiences as soon as 1937, had Edward VIII remained and stayed vocal in his support for the Nazis.

Comment: Check out - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_American_Bund and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends_of_New_Germany

Answer (score 4):

Fascism was already well established by the 1930's in Italy, and was one of the most popular and widely studied political movements in the West, with Fascist parties and leagues in virtually every European nation (think of the British Union of Fascists, for example). Even luminaries like H.G. Wells were doing speaking tours advocating for some form of Fascism (Wells called for some sort of "Liberal Fascism"). Had history gone a bit differently, Fascism and Totalitarianism would likely be considered the "gold standard" of governance today, and Mussolini consisered a towering figure of early to mid 20th century politics.

As for the United States, Fascism simply came in through the side door, as FDR's "Brain Trust" copied large elements of the Italian Fascist Corporate State's program to create the "New Deal".

There are two main reasons Fascism did not get entrenched in the United States -

1. The manifest failure of the New Deal. While it was sold as a way to undo the effects of the Great Depression, it simply extended it by as much as seven years. The book "[The Forgotten Man"](https://www.amazon.ca/Forgotten-Man-History-Great-Depression/dp/0060936428) goes into this in great depth. While it may not have been as obvious in an academic sense during the 1930's, Americans could certainly see the trains were not "running on time" - the worst year of the Depression was 1938, almost a full decade after the "Crash" of 1929.
2. Fascism was coming off the rails in Europe. While it certainly seemed that people like Mussolini and Giovanni Gentile had created a new form of Socialism based on "Syndicalism" rather than Marxism, it had essentially run out of steam in Italy, and was only making gains in fractured, weak and disorganized Eastern European nations. In more prosperous Western European nations, existing structures and institutions proved to be far more flexible and robust. Fascism works in low performance/low trust environments where it can be used to harness resources and manpower that otherwise be dissapated or would not be used. Once the Second World War got underway, the rigid and brittle nature of Fascism worked against it, and the destruction of the Fascist State in Italy discredited it forever.

America was a poor place to try to import Fascism since there were a great many independent institutions that could and did work outside of a Totalitarian framework. Culturally, Americans were not going to become Fascist anytime soon. In some alternate universe where WWII does not happen and the Depression drags on for decades, Fascism might be able to gain organic roots in America in the 1950's, as the previous generation dies off and people have grown up with it their entire lives.

So in real history, Fascist ideas were well known in the United States, and even copied to a certain extent in the 1930's as part of the "New Deal". Progressiveism simply served as the conduit. If the intent is to create an alternative history where Fascism becommes the norm, then continuing the Great Depression without a Second World War and allowing the old generation to die off is really what will be needed for this to happen.

Comment: Your last sentence is the core answer to the exam question. (How to make it work for his proposed fictional US).   Presentation-wise, I'd recommend puiling it out and headed by a bold "summary" header, or something like that.  (And I think your answer does a nice job of expressing why it would take a longer Depression to make Fascism seem more appealing to more people).

Answer (score 2):

Franklin Roosevelt *did* come into power in the USA in the 1930s, and he *was* a kindred spirit to the fascists -- the far *left* parties then rising in power in Europe.  He, Mussolini, and to some extent Hitler [were mutual admirers](https://townhall.com/columnists/dineshdsouza/2018/08/22/hitler-mussolini-and-fdr-the-secret-history-of-a-mutual-admiration-society-n2512040) who saw themselves as part of the same great movement.  FDR greatly expanded the size and pervasiveness of the American government, using the Depression as a convenient crisis to do so.  He subverted America's traditional political checks and balances by threatening to expand the Supreme Court and [pack it with cronies](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/roosevelt-announces-court-packing-plan) if the then-seated justices didn't rubber-stamp his power grabs.  He instituted [central economic planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Industrial_Recovery_Act_of_1933) and enforced price controls.

The reason he couldn't take it to the extreme that Mussolini and Hitler had done, was that the American people weren't as willing to go along with it as the Europeans were.  That's what would have to change for America to have gone as fully fascist (far-left) as Italy or Germany in the 1930s.

Answer (score 1):

American Nationalism in the 1930s looked very different than Nationalism in other countries.  In Europe, believing in your government above all else generally meant serving a regime.  But American Nationalism throughout most of the 20th century focused on the nations founding principles set forth in the US Constitution which opposed strong regimes and the oppression of individual rights.  To believe in America was inseparable from believing in individualism. So 9 times out of 10, Fascism would be unable to prey on Nationalist pride in a place where Nationalism inherently opposes it.

To really give Fascism a fighting chance in the US, you need to destroy the Constitution's power long before the 1930s.  One way to do this would be to kill off Alexander Hamilton during the American Revolution preventing him from writing his thesis supporting the constitution.  His writings were key in getting the States to rally behind the constitution.  Without them, the constitution would have likely failed achieve supremacy of law for the Federal government.  The Colonies would have formed either completely individual nations or at best a confederation.  Many of these states would not have a meaningful Bill of Rights, and those states could have easily become Fascist and possibly even helped to spread fascism to neighboring states as the movement grew.

Another option that keeps the US intact is to let the South win the Civil War.  If the South Conquered the North, they would have destroyed the constitution and replaced it with  ideals of dominance found in slavery cultures.  These ideals would have been much more consistent with Fascism and by the World Wars, and could have been enough to sway the whole of the United States to the Axis side of the conflict in Europe.